# How do you make elements in a JFrame fixed?

Tags: java, swing

I am busy coding a program in netbeans (java)for a school project. It has multiple JFrames. I just figured out how to make each frame full screen, but now all the elements are in the wrong places. What do I do? Is there a way for me to make sure that the elements are fixed and don’t move? Thank you

Comment: @c0der I think you mean [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: To layout components you use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). It also defines how layout changes when parent resizes. You may also want to read [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice)?

Comment: @Abra , thanks. I fixed my comment.